# Can linux load balance between multiple routes to the same subnet?

Tags: linux, routing, load-balancing

I'm looking for a way to load balance between multiple routes for the same subnet under linux.

The scenario is that we have multiple Linux machines (EC2 instances) each configured with a Strongswan VPN client.  Each one has access to the same subnet on a remote site.

We'd like to configure other machines to route to that subnet through those machines.  But the problem is that the VPN tunnels have rate limiting associated so we don't just want to route everything through one server.  It's also possible that one could go down for any reason so a solution involving a level of failover.

I've been unable to find much information on the subject.

Is this something that typically requires dedicated hardware, or did I miss something in iptables / nftables?

Comment: it's first about routing, then you need something to help distributing the load, where multiple next-hops or else iptables/nftables can be used, depending on the layout. For the base routing part, look at this old documentation to get the idea: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html. I'm afraid I can't give a real answer without a specific (detailed) problem. And with an EC2 environment everything will probably become more difficult

Comment: @A.B it's an interesting point about EC2. I've not checked what meds could be caused by AWS routing. But for now I'm only interested in the Linux problem of having multiple valid next-hop in the routing table and load balance or failover between them. Not sure how to be more specific than that.

Comment: What I mean: if you give all the interfaces, IP addresses and routing tables of all the involved nodes and various configuration coming along (eg: IPSec involved in this case), ideally a reproducible case, it's easier to give an answer based on that. If it's not given, it might mean it's dynamic or unknown or... and it becomes more difficult to give an answer and depending on the unknown parts, the answer might even be wrong. Or the answer will have to be very generic (in such case, the link I provided earlier would be the best bet).

Comment: @A.B Feel free to give a generic answer if you've got one.  The information you're asking for doesn't appear to be relevant to the question.  I don't have most of what you're asking for because I'm still in the design phase.